# Internal hyperref links do not work with res.cls

Tags: hyperref, document-classes

I am using the popular `res.cls` for my resume ([CTAN Link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/res?lang=en))

I would like to put internal links in my file. However, the following does not successfully place the internal links:

```
\documentclass{res}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:part1}

\hyperref[sec:part1]{Jump to Section 1}

\hyperref[sec:part2]{Jump to Section 2}

\section{Section 2}
\label{sec:part2}

\hyperref[sec:part1]{Jump to Section 1}

\hyperref[sec:part2]{Jump to Section 2}

\end{document}
```

However, if I use a built-in .cls the links are placed successfully:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:part1}

\hyperref[sec:part1]{Jump to Section 1}

\hyperref[sec:part2]{Jump to Section 2}

\section{Section 2}
\label{sec:part2}

\hyperref[sec:part1]{Jump to Section 1}

\hyperref[sec:part2]{Jump to Section 2}

\end{document}
```

What modifications need to be made to the `.cls` file in order for this to behave as expected?

Comment: `res` is an outdated class and `popular` is arguable ;-) Don't use it. The main cause is that `res` explicitly states `\nofiles` in the class file, which is totally absurd and leaves no user control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res.cls` is a strange class and should not be used, in my point of view. It has the explicit`\nofiles` statement in the class file, which prevents the generation of the auxiliary files such as `.aux`, which is needed desperately by `hyperref`.

Another issue is that `\section` is effectively redefined, so there is no counter used at all, i.e. `\refstepcounter` and `\label` is actually useless :-(

One possible solution (amongst not using `res.cls`) is to say `\let\nofiles\relax` before `\documentclass{res}`.

Using something like

```
\makeatletter
\@fileswtrue
\makeatother
```

does not solve the problem, since `\protected@write` is redefined within `\nofiles` to write to the terminal always, so nothing would be gained here really.

The `\label` issue can be solved by prepending the `\section` command with `\phantomsection`.

```
\let\nofiles\relax
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pretocmd{\section}{\phantomsection}{}{}
\begin{document}


\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:part1}

\hyperref[sec:part1]{Jump to Section 1}

\hyperref[sec:part2]{Jump to Section 2}

\clearpage
\section{Section 2}\label{sec:part2}

\hyperref[sec:part1]{Jump to Section 1}

\hyperref[sec:part2]{Jump to Section 2}

\end{document}
```

Much cleaner ways: Use `\hyperlink` or `cleveref` or `\nameref`.

Comment: I omitted a screenshot since there's nothing visually interesting to show